# Kernel of this action is trivial?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $S_n$ act on $S_n/H=\{ H,t_2 H,...,t_e H\}$ from the left and let $n\geq 5$, $e \geq 3$. Then the kernel of this action is trivial.

This supposedly follows because $e \geq 3$, but I haven't the slightest clue how? Now, the kernel is a normal subgroup of $S_n$, so it must be one of $S_n,A_n,\langle \mathrm{id} \rangle$. I'm actually not sure about the definition of the kernel of an action; Dummit/Foote defines the kernel of this particular action as $$\{ \sigma \in S_n \mid \sigma s_i H = s_i H, \forall s_i \in S_n \} = \cap_{s_i \in S_n} s_i H s_i^{-1}$$

I figure this is equivalent to $$\{ \sigma \in S_n \mid \sigma t_i H = t_i H, \forall t_i \in S_n//H \} = \cap_{t_i \in S_n//H} t_i H t_i^{-1}$$

In other words, those permutations stabilizing all the elements of $S_n/H$. When $e=2$ it can be checked "manually" that the kernel $A_n$, but showing that takes into account odd- and evenness and not the actual number $2$. How do I use the assumption $e\geq 3$ in proving the above assertion?

Comment: The kernel is contained in $H$. $e=[G:H]$. What is the index of $A_n$ in $S_n$ and how does the index of the kernel relate to the index of $[G:H]$?

Comment: @JackSchmidt $[S_n : A_n]=2$ but as far as the rest goes I haven't a clue what you're getting at :)

Comment: @JackSchmidt Hold on a sec... The kernel is contained in $H$ of index $\geq 3$, and must be normal. $H$ isn't normal, so the kernel must be trivial. Is that it?

Comment: yup, that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Denote that kernel of this action by $K$. Then $K, t_2K,\cdots, t_eK$ are pairwise different.

Comment: How do you deduce that?

Comment: @ErikVesterlund: Elements in $t_iK$ send $H$ to $t_iH$.

Comment: @ErikVesterlund: Is everything clear to you now?

Comment: I'd have to look into it, as is it doesn't provide any insights, sorry. Thanks for helping out though!

Comment: @ErikVesterlund: You are welcome. I think you have got the idea in your reply to Jack Schmidt's comment, so could you explain what is unclear to you in my answer?

Comment: That it's "unclear" is only due to my own shortcomings; I (almost) immediately understood how Jack's answer solved my hint, while yours I'd have to sit down and take a better look at. I shall look into your answer at a later time because I think it will give me better intuition for the "situation" :)

Comment: @ErikVesterlund: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I also think the fact in Jack Schmidt's comment that the kernel of the action is a subgroup of $H$ is the standard way to answer your question.(I chose the way in my answer just because I intended to use your notations $t_2,\dots,t_e$ so that $e$ explicitly appeared.)